# Get intermediate points of SciPy CubicSpline

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

I am trying to get an array of intermediate points after interpolation in SciPy. But there doesn't seem to be any direct method to do that. Can anyone help?

Sample Code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)
cs = CubicSpline(x, y)
xs = np.arange(-0.5, 9.6, 0.1)
plt.figure(figsize=(6.5, 4))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(xs, np.sin(xs), label='true')
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs), label="S")
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs, 1), label="S'")
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs, 2), label="S''")
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs, 3), label="S'''")
plt.xlim(-0.5, 9.5)
plt.legend(loc='lower left', ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `cs` on intermediate values? For instance, use `new_xs = np.arange(-0.5, 9.6, 0.05)` and plot `plt.plot(new_xs, cs(new_xs))`?

Comment: Sorry, I see that `xs` has more points than x to start with. The derivatives cannot be much more refined than what you have, with cubic interpolation. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to get value of CubicBezier, such as `cs(5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [CubicSpline documentation says](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.__call__), the object it returns is callable, with parameters

> - x : array_like
>     Points to evaluate the interpolant at.
> - nu : int, optional
>     Order of derivative to evaluate.
> - extrapolate : {bool, ‘periodic’, None}, optional

So, `cs(5)` gives the value of the spline at at 5, while  `cs(5, 2)` is its second derivative at 5, etc.